# What is the diff b/w this.name and this.state.name in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React has instance property and state property in react in constructor.

Instance property - Its not re-render the view. use to store the value.
State property - Its store and re-render the view.

Apart from above any other reason or difference or when should be use for both instance and state in constructor of React class component?.

Example:

```
class example extends Component{
  constructor(){
     this.state = {
       name: 'albert'
     };
    this.name = 'albert';
  }
}
```

Comment: One is part of the component state, one is a component property.

Answer (score 1):

When component state changes, it triggers component re-rendering (if it's not set to be ignored in [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)).

Changing instance property does not trigger re-rendering.

Answer (score 1):

simple difference for both that is view part rendering.
EX: When State is update the view also update. Sometimes view is need not to reload that time we can store the value in component instance as you mentioned **this.name**.

Just check with below link to more about state and instance 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your requirement, which kind of data you are storing within it.

When any state variable is updated, react calls `render` to make changes in DOM element, so if you want to make any changes in DOM you should use `state` otherwise instance.

> The current best practice is to use local **state to handle** the state of
>   your **user interface (UI)** state rather than data.

from [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00)

and instance properties when you just want to save some data to use in UI handling, calculations etc.
check this ref [react-components-elements-and-instances](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) for futher details

Answer (score 0):

Whenever state is updated, react calls the `render()` method to update the DOM with required changes, and it should always be updated using `setState()`. The instance variable will be useful for block level manipulations which would then update the state if required. So if you want to re-render the DOM use state variables, else use instance variables.